push_Enabled incorrect at first registration call
We've been noticing that for some reason at first app launch, the push_Enabled property is set to true at the registration call of the iOS SDK (currently 8.1.2), even though no push permissions are given, nor have we manually configured this.
Only at a later point, seconds to one minute after the first registration call, another registration call goes out where this property is set to false, as it should be.

push has been enabled in the SDK with value: 0 file: MarketingCloudSDKFoundation.m line: line: 1350

The message above is shown in between these registration calls which I think influences this value being correct in the latter one. We do not manually trigger this as far as I know. The setPushEnabled function is untouched.
Did we misconfigure something? Do we have to manually call setPushEnabled after the SDK setup to prevent this? Or is it actually a bug that this value is true at the first registration call, and only at a later point is set to false?
